# Showing the child route in a grandparent layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In reactjs new version of React-Router-Dom

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/">
      <Route index element={<Index />} />
      <Route path="home" element={<PageLayout />}>
        <Route="grandparent" element={<Grandparent />}>
          <Route="parent" element={<Parent />}>
            <Route="child" element={<Child />}>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
```

[here is now my sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWq8n.png)

I outlet all children components in its parent so the content box is also nested but I don't want that.
I want to keep the route hierarchy since my using it as breadcrumbs. Somehow I address that problem by hiding the parent component if the it is active based on `Navlink` but I think that was inappropriate

[content box will just change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNIZ2.png)

Comment: What exactly is the issue or question here? Please [edit] to clarify and to include a complete [mcve].